# What is the inverse of blobstore.create_gs_key

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Is there a way to reverse blobstore.create_gs_key("gs/xxxxxxx"), ie to recreate the file id from the returned string.

NB: I need to do that with a blob key (from datastore) that has been already deleted. I need the file name to retrieve the deleted file from Google Storage versioning.